# Whats the best way to manage divs in a controller in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

It's becoming increasingly annoying to manage my /divs in codeigniter.

There seems to be a a lot of times where I want to load multiple views under a more encompassing div.

I am forced to either include a opening div in the first view, and a closing div in the last view, or, I've also tried creating a view solely for opening and closing divs so that its easier to keep track of.

```
function index($page = '1-home')
{
        /*if (!$this->tank_auth->is_logged_in()) {
                redirect('/auth/login/');
        } else { */
        $this->blurb_model->session_load();
        $data['user_id'] = $this->tank_auth->get_user_id();
        $data['username'] = $this->tank_auth->get_username();
        $data['title'] = ucfirst($page); // Capitalize the first letter
        $data['title'] = $this->page_model->make_title($data['title']);
        $data['page'] = $page;
        //top of page
        $this->load->view('templates/head', $data);
        /* div wrapper */ $this->load->view('templates/wrapper-start', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/nav', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/logo');
        $this->load->view('leftbar/create', $data);
        $this->load->view('leftbar/category', $data);
        $this->load->view('leftbar/addfilter', $data);
        $this->load->view('page/board', $data);
        /* div wrapper */ $this->load->view('templates/wrapper-end', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);

}
```

Is there something I'm missing? Or an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about making a general template with the following sections and using CSS to style it:

1. Head
2. Navigation
3. Left/Rightcolumn
4. Maincontent
5. Footer

   ```
   <div id="innerWrapper">
       <div id="header">
           <div id="logo"><!-- logo HTML -></div>
           <div id="navigation"><?php echo $navigation; // or navigation html and logic in here ?></div>
       </div>
       <div id="mainbody">
           <div id="leftmenu"><?php echo $leftmenu; ?></div>
           <div id="maincontent"><?php echo $content; ?></div>
       </div>
       <div id="footer">
           <div id="column1"><!-- HTML -></div>
           <div id="column2"><!-- HTML -></div>
       </div>
   </div>
   ```

You can then assign $leftmenu and $content (and any other variable in your template) as the following:

```
// this assigns the returned HTML to the $content variable in your maintemplate
$data['content'] = $this->load->view('somtetemplate, NULL, TRUE);  

$this->load->view('innerpage', $data);  // this is your main template
```

Does that make sense? It'll make for better organisation IMO.

Comment: or even just a header, content, footer type deal where the content view changes based on what page it is.

Comment: @user1062354 Do you know why it is loading all the php content prior to loading all the html?  I followed this format, and, for instance, the wrapper is being loaded UNDER the leftbar.

Comment: @Ricky Mason $this->load->view('somtetemplate, NULL, TRUE);

NULL = variables you want to pass to the template
TRUE = Instead of outputting the html to the browser, it stores it in the $data['content'] variable

Can you post your full controller code?  I'll take a look

Comment: @User1062354, thank you for the reply. I am not sure why, but the data only passed correctly when I removed NULL `$data['head'] = $this->load->view('templates/head', $data, TRUE);`

Comment: @Ricky Mason  NULL meant you are passing no data to the view.  So any array you pass to it via $data would pass on the variables to the view, which is what you have done.  My apologies for not clarifying that before.